# Convert ordered string to mysql Datetime

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have an API that returns a date string like this : `190416102906`

Which means : `19 April 2016 at 10:29:06`.

I want to store it in my Mysql Datetime but I don't know how to format it. It need to go from `190416102906` to `2016-04-19 10:29:06`.

I've tried to use something like this but I probably didn't understand how it works :

```
$date_reponse = '190416102906';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("dmYHis",$date_reponse);
$newDate = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your format was incorrect : "dmYHis"

`Y` = Year format with 4 digit.

use `y` year with 2 digit (`dmyHis`)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("dmyHis",$date_reponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just got the format the wrong way round and you need a lower case `y` for a 2 char year

```
$date_reponse = '190416102906';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("dmyHis",$date_reponse);
$newDate = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Sorry, mistook the date for a timestamp the first time round